# SharePoint 2013 Workflow Tasks and Outlook

Tags: 2013, workflow, outlook

I'm trying to find a way to have the 'Open this task' button in Outlook when a task notification from a SharePoint 2013 Workflow is sent to a user.

We have been working on upgrading our SharePoint 2010 installation to 2013. Most of our sites are easily converted, but we have one business critical workflow that is keeping us from finishing the upgrade. This workflow is a simple approval process which assigns tasks to users in sequence. If all users approve, it sends an email into our ticketing service so we can apply the change requested. I am trying to duplicate this functionality using a 2013 workflow and the Task Process action.

However, whenever the task is sent out to the users, the 'Open this task' button in Outlook does not appear. I've done some digging, and I believe it is tied to the `Content-Class` header of the task alert email. From SharePoint 2010, the header is `MSWorkflowTasks`, where from 2013 it is `IPM.Note.Microsoft.Workflow.2013`. No other headers are significantly different between the two emails.

Is there a way I can change the headers of those emails sent from 2013 to `MSWorkflowTasks`, or am I going about this the wrong way? Having this button is fairly important in our process, as it does allow us to (at least slightly) obfuscate the workflow process from the users, and the users have grown dependant on it.

Comment: That doesn't seem too hard or lengthy to replicate. Is there a reason why you haven't tried to start from scratch? Is this a VS or SPD workflow? BTW I'm going to ruin your 1 rep, 1 gold, 1 silver, 1 bronze badge.

Comment: I've made several workflows trying to get this to work correctly, but have yet to succeed. I'm down to just using a filler template ("Test", nonsense figures, etc) until I get this figured out. I'm using SharePoint Designer to generate the workflow. I think VS would be too powerful for what I need, considering SPD gives me everything I need to accomplish the original objective.

Comment: Are you giving the users the right permissions? There is a permission level that allows user to be able to connect externally to lists, and this permission level may be the cause. Otherwise, try to recreate a simple approval workflow with full permissions to see what the workflow task looks like in Outlook. What version of Outlook are you using?

Comment: When I do my testing, I use a site that I have full control over. I have not yet checked what the task looks like under a user that does not have full control. We are using Outlook 2013, but we _can_ see the task button with tasks from SP 2010. The only difference I can see is the SP version and the email headers.

Comment: Is the SharePoint site part of the trusted sites in the IE settings? Is SharePoint on the same domain as Exchange? What's the difference (in environment/habitat) from your 2010 and 2013 environments?

Comment: Both of our farms are trusted sites, and sit on the same domain as Exchange. Both farms are in a virtual environment (different servers, same VM host, and the same base image), with each farm having one each application, web app, and database server. The configuration of each farm is different, with 2013 being closer to default. 2010 was before my time, and I'm not a SharePoint expert, so I'm unsure of exactly how they may differ for settings, but we did preserve as many settings as we could with 2013.

Comment: Is this still an issue or have you found the solution?

Comment: We have not been able to find a solution to this yet. Our current solution is setting up the workflow email to have embedded links to the approve/decline/reassign functions (works but not pretty). However, we would still like to have the 'Open this task' button if it would be possible to do so.

Comment: Updates? I am running into this issue as well.

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, we added direct links, and additionally trained users to treat the emails as notifications - most now go directly to the Task List that drives everything and operates on that. We gave up on getting the button to be available some time ago.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem here, the only way to solve it was to re install a new environment with default values (out of the box) and migrate the old contents to the new servers. It seems like the old farm had a defective service (we never detected the error until today).
Remember that deploying a complete farm only with scripts must be done carefully and the minimun privilege policy for accounts can be a headache.